# GXT Performance Issues

Tags: performance, gwt, gxt

We are working on a rather complex system using GXT. While everything works great on FF, IE (especially IE6) is a different story (looking at more than 10 seconds until the browser renders the page).

I understand that one of the main reasons is DOM manipulation which is a disaster under IE6 (See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html).

This can be thought to be a generic problem of a front-end Javascript framework (i.e. GWT) but a simple code (see below) that executes the same functionality proofs otherwise. In fact, under IE6 - getSomeGWT() takes 400ms while getSomeGXT() takes 4 seconds. That's a x10 factor which makes a huge different for the user experience !!!

```
private HorizontalPanel getSomeGWT() {
        HorizontalPanel pointsLogoPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
        for (int i=0; i<350; i++) {
            HorizontalPanel innerContainer = new HorizontalPanel();
            innerContainer.add(new Label("some GWT text"));
            pointsLogoPanel.add(innerContainer);
        }
        return pointsLogoPanel;
    }

    private LayoutContainer getSomeGXT() {
        LayoutContainer pointsLogoPanel = new LayoutContainer();
        pointsLogoPanel.setLayoutOnChange(true);
        for (int i=0; i<350; i++) {
            LayoutContainer innerContainer = new LayoutContainer();
            innerContainer.add(new Text("just some text"));
            pointsLogoPanel.add(innerContainer);
        }
        return pointsLogoPanel;
    }
```

So to solve/mitigate the issue one would need to -
a. Reduce the number of DOM manipulations; or
b. Replace them with innerHTML.

AFAIK, (a) is simply a side effect of using GXT and (b) is only possible with UiBinder which isn't supported yet by GXT.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with:

```
pointsLogoPanel.setLayoutOnChange(true);
```

This will enforce calling the layout for each additional component and may be causing the differences you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

GXT layout containers are more powerful, but do come at a cost. They can be quite powerful especially when using layouts like RowLayout etc.

My first question would be, what capabilities do you want for these nested containers? dynamically sized, advanced resizing options / proportioning? Or do the GWT containers or plain HTML containers suffice?

If you do decide to use GXT Layout Containers, you should start by disabling the layoutOnChange option. As enabling that option causes additional processing each time you add a child to the container, and potentially gets the browser to re-render at that point in time.

So with layoutOnChange disabled, simply call layout() on your pointsLogoPanel after the for loop. Though since you haven't even added it to a parent container yet, you can simply call layout() on the parent container once pointsLogoPanel is added. This won't solve all the performance problems but it'll probably go a long way.